# change reference category in linear mixed model

Tags: statistics, mixed-models

I need help in changing the reference category in the following linear mixed model. I want to choose Q1*2001 as my reference group.

```r
library(lme4)       # linear mixed-effects models
library(lmerTest)   # test for linear mixed-effects models
library(gtsummary)


names(trajectories)

m1 <- lmer(distance ~ (as.factor(year))* Quintile + (1 | id), data = trajectories)

summary(m1)

m2 <- tbl_regression (m1,
                include= c("as.factor(year):Quintile"),
                pvalu_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 3),
                estimate_fun = function(x) gtsummary::style_sigfig(x, digits = 3),
                add_estimate_to_reference_rows = TRUE,
                )%>% 
  bold_p() %>%  
  bold_labels()

print(m2)
```

[image]

```r
====================
m1 <- lmer(distance ~ yr_qun + (1 | id), data = trajectories)

summary(m1)

contrasts(trajectories$yr_qun) <- contr.treatment(50, base = 1)


m2 <- tbl_regression (m1,
                include= c("yr_qun"),
                pvalu_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 3),
                estimate_fun = function(x) gtsummary::style_sigfig(x, digits = 3),
                add_estimate_to_reference_rows = TRUE,
                )%>% 
  bold_p() %>%  
  bold_labels() %>% 
as_kable()

print(m2)

=====================
```

here is my dummy data

dput(trajectories)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L,
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L,
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), year = c(2001L,
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L,
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L,
2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L,
2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L,
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L,
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L,
2006L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L,
2009L, 2010L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L,
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L,
2010L), distance = c(15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5,
24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5,
23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5,
24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5,
24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24,
25.5, 20.5, 24, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5,
23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24), age = c(8L, 9L, 10L, 11L,
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L,
18L, 19L, 20L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L,
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 6L, 7L, 8L,
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L,
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 20L,
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L,
48L), Quintile = structure(c(5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L,
5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L,
1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L,
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L,
3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L,
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L), levels = c("Q1",
"Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L), levels = c("F", "M"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-83L))

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Here's an example of how to change the reference group using the `contrasts()` function (the second example in the comment). https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/715#issuecomment-747490288

Comment: @ Daniel D. Sjoberg many thanks for your suggestion and help. I tried to use contrasts(d$grade) <- contr.treatment(3, base = 2) used in the second example. as I have an interaction term (year*Quintile) so how should I define, (contrasts(trajectories$year*Quintile) <- contr.treatment(50, base = 1). i tried using this but I got an error  Error in contrasts(trajectories$year * Quintile) <- contr.treatment(50,  : 
  object 'Quintile' not found

Comment: I would first try setting the contrast for the individual variable rather than the contrast. If that doesn't work, try creating the interaction term manually

Comment: @ Daniel D. Sjoberg thanks for your suggestion.     i tried by creating interaction term manually and run the code but as i have 50 categories in interaction so i get an error        m1 <- lmer(distance ~ yr_qun + (1 | id), data = trajectories)
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 5.56955 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?

Comment: @ Daniel . Sjoberg I also notice the interaction term between Q1 and year is not reported for all of the years. I can understand that Q1 for 2001 is the reference category, but for other years from 2002 to 2010,  Q1 is not reported am I doing anything wrong (see picture)? i want Q1 *2001 is referecne group. many thanks for all your help.

Comment: @ Daniel . Sjoberg, thanks I sorted the above code in the original data, just want to know how to omit na in  tbl_regression?